# PandasDataFrame to json

Tags: python, pandas

I need to convert a Pandas DataFrame to a json.

Below is a sample of my data.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [
        {'project_no' :1, 'country' :'USA','category' : 'Beverages','product': 'Milk','count' : 2},
        {'project_no' :1,'country' :'USA','category' :'Beverages','product':'Juice','count' :5},
        {'project_no' :1,'country' :'USA','category' :'Snacks','product':'Potato Chips' , 'count' :2},
        {'project_no' :1,'country' :'USA','category' :'Oils', 'product':'Canola', 'count' :5},
        {'project_no' :1,'country' :'USA','category' :'Oils', 'product':'Olive', 'count' :8},
        {'project_no' :1,'country' :'CAN','category' :'Beverages','product':'Milk','count' :7},
        {'project_no' :1,'country' :'CAN','category' :'Beverages','product':'Juice','count' :8},
        {'project_no' :1,'country' :'CAN','category' :'Snacks','product':'Potato Chips' , 'count' :8},
        {'project_no' :1,'country' :'CAN','category' :'Oils', 'product':'Canola', 'count' :3},
        {'project_no' :1,'country' :'CAN','category' :'Oils', 'product':'Olive','count' :4}
    ] )
```

How can I convert the above DataFrame to the below json.

> ```
> {{
>     'project': [{
>             'country': 'USA',
>             'category': [{
>                     'Beverages': [{
>                             'product': 'Milk',
>                             'count': 2
>                         }, {
>                             'product': 'Juice',
>                             'count': 5
>                         }
>                     ]
>                 }, {
>                     'Snacks': [{
>                             'product': 'Potato Chips',
>                             'count': 2
>                         }
>                     ]
>                 }, {
>                     'Oils': [{
>                             'product': 'Canola',
>                             'count': 5
>                         }, {
>                             'product': 'Olive',
>                             'count': 8
>                         }
>                     ]
>                 }
>             ]
>
>         }, {
>             'country': 'CAN',
>             'category': [{
>                     'Beverages': [{
>                             'product': 'Milk',
>                             'count': 7
>                         }, {
>                             'product': 'Juice',
>                             'count': 8
>                         }
>                     ]
>                 }, {
>                     'Snacks': [{
>                             'product': 'Potato Chips',
>                             'count': 8
>                         }
>                     ]
>                 }, {
>                     'Oils': [{
>                             'product': 'Canola',
>                             'count': 3
>                         }, {
>                             'product': 'Olive',
>                             'count': 4
>                         }
>                     ]
>                 }
>             ]
>         }
>
>     ]
>   }
> }
> ```

This is what I have so far.

```
(
    df
    .groupby
    (
        [
            'country','category'
        ]
    )
    ['product','count']
    .apply(lambda x: x[['product','count']].to_dict('r'))
    .reset_index()
    .to_json(orient='records')     
)
```

This is the result of my try.

> [{
>           "country": "CAN",
>           "category": "Beverages",
>           "0": [{
>                   "product": "Milk",
>                   "count": 7
>               }, {
>                   "product": "Juice",
>                   "count": 8
>               }
>           ]
>       }, {
>           "country": "CAN",
>           "category": "Oils",
>           "0": [{
>                   "product": "Canola",
>                   "count": 3
>               }, {
>                   "product": "Olive",
>                   "count": 4
>               }
>           ]
>       }, {
>           "country": "CAN",
>           "category": "Snacks",
>           "0": [{
>                   "product": "Potato Chips",
>                   "count": 8
>               }
>           ]
>       }, {
>           "country": "USA",
>           "category": "Beverages",
>           "0": [{
>                   "product": "Milk",
>                   "count": 2
>               }, {
>                   "product": "Juice",
>                   "count": 5
>               }
>           ]
>       }, {
>           "country": "USA",
>           "category": "Oils",
>           "0": [{
>                   "product": "Canola",
>                   "count": 5
>               }, {
>                   "product": "Olive",
>                   "count": 8
>               }
>           ]
>       }, {
>           "country": "USA",
>           "category": "Snacks",
>           "0": [{
>                   "product": "Potato Chips",
>                   "count": 2
>               }
>           ]
>       }      ]

What can I do SOF say my question is mostly code.
It is not a lot of code in reality.
Causing me some pain.
I don't have much to write.
Still I had to keep writing.
Please this check is really silly.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html ????

Comment: @rayryeng-ReinstateMonica no that wont give the result. Looking to get the nesting correctly.

Comment: Ok. So what have you tried? Please provide a [mcve] showing where you are having difficulties in your attempt.

Comment: @rayryeng-ReinstateMonica Added what I have so far.